# Disk based cache using ProviderBase

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

Has anyone managed to create a disk based cache provider using the ProviderBase available in .NET4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/56161e9e-7fa3-48e8-9dfe-9f7a28f4d58e/filebased-cache-for-web.aspx